# Dataprep importing files with different number of columns into a dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I am trying to create a parameterized dataset that imports files from GCS and puts them under each other. This all works fine (Import Data > Parameterize).

To give a bit of context, I store each day a .csv file with a different name referring to that date.

Now it happens that my provider added a new column since last month into the files. This means that files before this date have **8 columns**, whereas from this date **9 columns**.

However, when I parameterize, Dataprep only takes into account the columns that are matching (thus **8 columns** only). Ideally I would want empty observations for the rows coming from files that did not have this new column.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameterized datasets only work on a fixed schema as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Create-Dataset-with-Parameters_118228628#structuring-your-data):

> Avoid creating datasets with parameters where individual files or tables have differing schemas.

This fixed schema is generated using one of the file found during the *creation* of the dataset with parameters.

If the schema has changed, then you can "*refresh*" it by editing the dataset with parameters and clicking save. If all the matching files contain 9 columns, you should now see 9 columns in the transformer.

Comment: Makes sense. Good tip on the refresh as I was now always re importing the entire dataset to get the new scheme.